# jquery not() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="row">
<img src="images/image.png" width="30" height="30" alt=""/>
<a href="#">View</a>
</div>


$(".row").not(".row a").click(function(){

             // irrelevant
        })
```

I can't figure out why this isn't working. I don't want to call the function when "View" is clicked.

Comment: You're missing `"`It's all I can see.

Comment: You know, it'd be really useful to see this code in action, perhaps at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar. Incidentally, if you press F12 to open the developer tools, and go to the console tab, are any errors reported?

Comment: I'll try to put something together. From what it seems jquery doesn't recognize the A being clicked at all. I wasn't even able to get its class. I'm guessing it has something to do with the css

Comment: You've specifically told jQuery *not* to react to the `a` being clicked, so it won't. What is it that you're trying to do? There may be an easier, or at least alternative, approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
 $(".row").click(function(){

 });


$('.row a').click(function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();   //this cancel the other events 
});
```

Comment: In the second example you need to declare `e` as a function argument.

Answer (score 2):

Is this ,what you were looking for?

```
$(".row").on('click',':not(a)', function(){
});
```

Adds `'click'` event listener on all child elements of `'.row'`, except `'a'` elements.